# dask bag foldby with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, mapreduce, dask

I get a very uninformative `FutureWarning` message from `dask` / `numpy` when doing a `foldby` on a `dask.bag` that contains numpy arrays.

```
def binop(a, b):
    print('binop')
    return a + b[1]

def combine(a, b):
    print('combine')
    return a + b[1]

seq = ((np.random.randint(0, 5, size=1)[0], np.ones(5,)) for _ in range(50))
db.from_sequence(seq, partition_size=10)\
    .foldby(0, binop=binop, initial=np.zeros(5,), combine=combine)\
    .compute()
```

The aim is to just add up a bunch of `NumPy` arrays. That produces the correct results but also produces a number of `FutureWarning` messages (looks like one per partition) from `NumPy` although it looks as though they are coming from `dask`.

> dask/async.py:247: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
>     return func(*args2)

Just adding up two `numpy` arrays without `dask` does not produce that so there's clearly some involvement with the parallel `.foldby` here. It looks like the warnings are produced before any computation is even done.

- how do I determine if the warning is something I should be concerned about?
- how do I make the warning go away if I should be concerned about it?

I'm using python `3.6` dask `0.14.1` and numpy `1.12.1`

[dask.bag.foldby](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/bag-api.html#dask.bag.Bag.foldby)

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @MRocklin's answer I started looking into this a bit more. So the offending code in `dask.async.py` is [this](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/0.14.1/dask/async.py#L242)

```
def _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk=None):
....
    if isinstance(arg, list):
        return [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in arg]
    elif istask(arg):
        func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
        args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
        return func(*args2)
```

is it possible that `dask` is in fact trying to iterate over the `numpy` array in `args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]`, I don't know the internal well enough (at all in fact) to judge what those variables contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has something to do with `cytoolz.itetoolz.reduceby` and the `init` value.  Changing the init from `init=np.zeros((5,))` to `init=lambda: np.zeros((5,))` at least gets rid of the warning message.

The warning is produced by [this line](https://github.com/pytoolz/cytoolz/blob/master/cytoolz/itertoolz.pyx#L879)

```
cpdef dict reduceby(object key, object binop, object seq, object init='__no__default__'):
...
    cdef bint skip_init = init == no_default
```

which compares the passed in init value (`np.zeros((5,))`) to the string `"__no__default__"` causing `numpy` to fail the element wise comparison of `carray` and `str`.

So to answer my own questions:

- no, you don't need to worry about that warning, but it might slow down the program in the future
- avoid the warning altogether by using a callable as the `init` value
- it doesn't seem this will have any major negative consequences, but keep in mind that the `init` callable will be called once per executor process

Answer (score 2):

This warning is indeed from numpy.  A quick search through the code base yields [these lines](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/69b0c42bca27dd5d5522de306bcd7db7deccbfad/numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c#L970-L982):

```
    if (!strcmp(ufunc_name, "equal") ||
            !strcmp(ufunc_name, "not_equal")) {
        /* Warn on non-scalar, return NotImplemented regardless */
        assert(nin == 2);
        if (PyArray_NDIM(out_op[0]) != 0 ||
                PyArray_NDIM(out_op[1]) != 0) {
            if (DEPRECATE_FUTUREWARNING(
                    "elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar "
                    "instead, but in the future will perform elementwise "
                    "comparison") < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Dask might make this a bit worse because you'll get the warning once in each process (dask.bag uses a process pool by default).

Also, if your computations are bound by numpy then you might consider switching to the threaded scheduler rather than the multiprocessing scheduler

```
mybag.compute(get=dask.threaded.get)
```

See http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-choice.html

Comment: What I still don't understand though is what `dask` is doing to the arrays to produce that warning. The comment for that case read `This condition basically means "we are doomed", b/c the "flexible" dtypes -- strings and void -- cannot have their own ufunc loops registered ...`. That makes no sense as the `dtype` of the arrays is `float64`, not `string` or `void`.  See modified question above

Comment: Dask.bag is just calling the functions that you have provided.  It doesn't introduce any special logic of its own.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that if `init` is a callable it'll be called once for each executor? That's what it looks like from the `cytoolz` code